# Как поменять свойство input date при значениях min и max

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

Необходимо отменить стандартное поведение input с указанием даты.
Если ввести в первом input нужную дату, то второй input автоматически подставляет возможные даты.

Каким образом можно отменить это стандартное действе, чтобы так и оставалось `дд мм гггг`

Ниже код из Angular. Где currentDate - это текущая дата.

```
<input
  [max]="eDate || currentDate"
  [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': reportsForm.controls.bDate.touched && reportsForm.controls.bDate.invalid }"
  class="form-control"
  formControlName="bDate"
  style="width: 100% !important;" type="date"
>

<input
  [min]="bDate"
  [max]="currentDate"
  [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': reportsForm.controls.eDate.touched && reportsForm.controls.eDate.invalid }"
  class="form-control"
  formControlName="eDate"
  style="width: 100% !important;"
  type="date"
>
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks